# Is there a name for continuous functions $\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that can be continuously extended to $\overline{\Omega}$?

Tags: general-topology, terminology

Given topological spaces $X$ and $Y$ together with a subset $\Omega \subseteq X$, is there a name for those continuous functions $f : \Omega \rightarrow Y$ such that $f$ can be extended to a continuous function $\overline{f} : \overline{\Omega} \rightarrow Y$? Where $\overline{\Omega}$ is the topological closure of $\Omega$. I am especially interested in the case where $\Omega$ is relatively compact and $Y = \mathbb{R}$; in this case, every such function is (obviously) bounded.

Comment: Such function is *the restriction to* $\Omega$ of a continuous function $\overline{\Omega} \rightarrow Y$.

Comment: @Did, of course. $g$ is an extension of $f$ iff $f$ is a restriction of $g$.

Comment: Which is why my comment answers your question, thank you.

Comment: I have seen such $f$ called *continuous up to the boundary of $\Omega$*. Not particularly snappy, though.

Comment: If you're looking for a name for the entire space of such functions, I'd go with just $C(\overline\Omega)$. As long as $Y$ is $T_1$, there's no ambiguity: continuous functions with identical restrictions to a dense set are identical, so the restriction map is injective.

Comment: @tomasz No, you need Hausdorff for that. Consider the line with doubled origin and the two natural embeddings of $\mathbb{R}$ into it to see that $T_1$ is not enough.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Good point. I thought that at first, but then somehow convinced myself $T_1$ would be enough. Still, $Y={\bf R}$ satisfies this abundantly. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know of any such name in a general case nor in the special case that you ask about.

But if you are willing to make your special case still more special by assuming also that $X$ is a metric space, then you can use the theorem that a continuous function $f : \Omega \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ continuously extends to $\overline\Omega$ if and only if $f$ is uniformly continuous. You'll find a discussion of some more general cases [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_continuity).

Comment: Thank you. This is useful.